# Метод для помещения текста сообщения Exception в строку

Tags: java, исключения

Подскажите с помощью какого метода возможно поместить в строку сообщение исключения? Например, что-то типа этого

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

Comment: именно сообщение или имя класса тоже?

Comment: именно сообщение. Я догадываюсь, что e.getMessage(), но происходит возврат `null`. Это, видимо, происходит потому, что сам exception не проброшен(в смсл не отработал) в программе и соответственно нет сообщения?

Comment: подозреваю, что если null значит сообщения там нет.

Comment: Разобрался. Просто само исключение не возникало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получить краткое описание исключения можно методом `toString()`:

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3};
try {
    int b = a[10];
} catch(Exception e) {
    String exception = e.toString();
    System.out.println(exception);  // java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
}
```

[Пример](https://ideone.com/bdzImu).